# Python function return problems

Tags: python, return

I have a very simply code looks like following:

```
   def divider(numberA, numberB):
       numberC = numberA%numberB

       if numberC != 0:
            divider(numberB, numberC)
       else:
            print numberB
            return numberB

   if __name__=="__main__":
       print divider(60,25)
```

I know I should put a return inside the `numberC !=0` loop. However, if I stick to my current code (without return) I will get output like this:

```
5 
None
```

My question is why these two numbers in the output are different in values ?

Answer (score 1):

You are ignoring the return value of the recursive call:

```
if numberC != 0:
    divider(numberB, numberC)
```

You need to explicitly return that result:

```
if numberC != 0:
    return divider(numberB, numberC)
```

You see `None` as the return value of `divider(60, 25)` because your outermost call never returned anything, so the default behaviour is to return `None` instead.

Your code does this:

```
divider(60, 25)
 |  numberC = 60 % 25 = 10
 |  numberC != 0 is True:
 |      divider(25, 10)
 |       |  numberC = 25 % 10 = 5
 |       |  numberC != 0 is True:
 |       |      divider(10, 5)
 |       |       |  numberC = 10 % 5 = 0
 |       |       |  numberC != 0 is False
 |       |       |      print numberB -> "5"
 |       |       \      return numberB = 5
 |       \  function ends, return None
 \  function ends, return None
```

Comment: @Mrk421: not really, not without capturing `sys.stdout` so you can catch the string `print` writes to it, then converting that back to an integer..

Comment: Martijn, thanks. A further question: why the result is not None 5 but 5 None? Means why it print 5 first then None ? I would expect the main first get the return value from divider(60,25) which is None then the program run divider(25,10) and following codes.  Thanks

Comment: @Mrk421: no, you are printing `5` *first*, then returning that value. The rest of the stack of calls then return `None`, which is finally printed by another `print` statement.